# how to login user after getting access token from api in vuejs?

Tags: python, vue.js, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I've not got idea what to do after getting access token from vuejs and how can i login user through the token.

After i build login frontend, I've now got  connected with django backend . I am using simplejwt.
I got successfully got token but how can i login? It is not logging in when i check api backend, just i am getting only access tokens and refresh tokens.

This is my snippet of store.js,

```
actions: {
userLogin(context, { email, password }) {
    getAPI
      .post("/token/", {
        email: email,
        password: password
      })
      .then(response => {
        context.commit("updateStorage", {
          access: response.data.access,
          refresh: response.data.refresh
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
}
```

getAPI i used from another which creates and connects to baseurl.

Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add token to your request to the headers.

Comment: I believe we could offer a more precise answer.
Such as:
You have manage to retrieve the token from the API and store it in the browser. Now all the request that need to the authorized will have to use this token. The documentation of the API your are consuming will tell you where to put this token.
I is commonly in one of those places: the API path, in the request header, in the body.